# Where could I ask a question about urban or regional planning?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I think that urban or regional planners might be able to help me. I want to know if there is research available that indicates how far people are willing to drive from a highway to refuel. If anybody has any ideas other than urban/regional planners, that would be great.

Comment: Before you ask anything, have you checked: https://stackexchange.com/sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was once a [proposal for an Urban Planning Stack Exchange at Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110962/urban-planning) but it has been deleted, presumably due to inactivity.